# AngularJs using a non injected service inside callbacks

Tags: angularjs, callback

I'm facing a problem I've solved in a nasty way but I'm proposing it here to see if there is a better way.

I'm using `angular-websocket` to send data over internet and I made a simple service called `Protocol` that uses `$websocket` with a messaging workflow.

Here is an oversimplified version of the `Protocol` service:

```
app.service('Protocol', [ '$websocket',
function ($websocket) {
    this.variable = 'to be changed in event' ;

    this.connect = function() {
        this.ws = $websocket('ws://mydomain.org') ;

        this.ws.onOpen(function() {
            // when i'm here the this pointer is a $websocket, not Protocol
            // so i made Protocol a global variable to be able to use it here
            Protocol.variable = 'new value' ;
        });
}])
```

As described in the comment I made Protocol global to be able to use it inside the `onOpen`. Due to the fact that the callback is called by `$websocket` then the `this` pointer inside `onOpen` is not `Protocol`.

Is there a cleaner way to change the `this.variable` without adding any global?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I always throw this into a local var so that I can access it without worrying about this rescoping.

```js
app.service('Protocol', [ '$websocket',
    function ($websocket) {
        this.variable = 'to be changed in event' ;

        this.connect = function() {
            var me = this;

            me.ws = $websocket('ws://mydomain.org') ;

            me.ws.onOpen(function() {
            // when i'm here the this pointer is a $websocket, not Protocol
            // so i made Protocol a global variable to be able to use it here
            me.variable = 'new value' ;
        });
}])
```

If you don't like that you could also bind your function

```js
app.service('Protocol', [ '$websocket',
    function ($websocket) {
        this.variable = 'to be changed in event' ;

        this.connect = (function() {
            this.ws = $websocket('ws://mydomain.org') ;

            this.ws.onOpen(function() {
                // when i'm here the this pointer is a $websocket, not Protocol
                // so i made Protocol a global variable to be able to use it here
                this.variable = 'new value' ;
            });
        }).bind(this)
}])
```

Comment: First method is obvious, I like it for maintainability of source code, the second looks more tricky.

Comment: I agree that the first method is preferable but there are some situations where binding is necessary. The binding gets really messy when you need to nest callbacks